# AVR timer programming

Tags: timer, microcontroller, avr

I was studying avr timers (Mazidi) in that book where a program was given in timer chapter it said whenever we need to calculate the value to enter inside TCNT0 ,we should calculate like this. for example 8Mhz, 256 prescalar , 1 s delay

```
     8 Mhz = .125 usec 
     256 x 0.125 = 32 usec
     for 1 ms delay 
     1sec / 32usec = 31250 clock cycles = 0x7A12
     so the value for TCNT0 is 
     1+FFFF-7A12 = 0x8255 //what this step means
```

Also when polling we look for TIFRs 0th bit for 1. when it becomes 1 we stop the timer and stop the clock source, but why we do this

```
     TIFR = 0x1 //clears TIFR??
```

in the book it was written it clears TIFR . How is this possible when that bit is already 1, writing 1 on it makes  it clear?

Comment: Usually you will see something like W1C in the bit/register description.  "write one to clear"  Not uncommin for interrupt flag registers to be cleared using a write one clear (often you read the flag register, operate on the flags then write what you read back clearing the bits you knew about, read again, if any other flags are set, deal with those, write what you read back, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
1+FFFF-7A12 = 0x8255 //what this step means
```

This is not the usual way to use a timer, but it subtracts your number from 0 (which is equivalent to 0xFFFF + 1) so that it "counts down" and trips when the timer reaches 0.

It makes much more sense to us TOC (timer output compare) instead.

```
TIFR = 0x1 //clears TIFR??
```

Yes. This register is not a memory location. It is mapped to a memory location. Some registers do work this way.